# Looping thru an array of objects to display content in an erb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model `Comments`. `Comments` has_many `votes`.  While displaying the `comments` I have to to display the up or down arrow based on the votes given to the `comments` by the `user`. So in my erb file I have `@comment`. `@comment.votes` has all the `votes` for that `comments` irrespective of the `user`. So i have to loop thru the`@comment.votes` to check `vote.user.id = @comment.user.id`. how can i achieve this in an erb file?

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to try a named_scope/scope on Vote, something like:

```
named_scope :for_user, lambda do |user_id|
  :conditions => ["comments.user_id = (?)", user_id]
end
```

Which lets you do something like:

```
@comments.votes.for_user(current_user.id)
```